# find the min of this inequality

Tags: inequality

I want to minimize $$\displaystyle\min_{x\in\Bbb R}\bigl\{\max\{|1-\lambda_{1}x|,|1-\lambda_{2}x|,\cdots,|1-\lambda_{n}x|\}\bigr\},$$ where $0<\lambda_1<\lambda_2<\cdots<\lambda_n.$

I think this result $x=\dfrac{2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_n}.$ I hope can someone can give me some good methods. Thank you.

Comment: How did you come up with your result? If $x=0$, then everything in the inner set if $1$, therefore the minimum is at most $1$, which isn't reflected in your result.

Comment: Maybe it would help if OP posted some context to the problem. The notation makes me think we are considering something to do with the eigenvalues of $I-A$ where $A$ is a positive definite matrix. Information like this of where the problem came from can be really useful in solving it.

Comment: Look from the graphics,when $|1-\lambda_{1}x|=|1-\lambda_{n}x|$

Comment: @Clayton You're right, this $x$ is the value where the min is attained (at least, for sure, when $n=2$). Not the minimum, ie not the value of the function at this point.

Comment: this problem from this:we have

Comment: You could consider the reals broken into intervals like $I_k = (\frac{1}{λ_{k+1}}, \frac{1}{λ_{k}}]$.  (Suitably define $I_1$ and $I_{n+1}$ to complete the reals.).  Now for $x$ in each interval the objective can be simplified without absolute signs, to be $ \max [ (1-λ_i x) $ for $i \le k,  (λ_i x -1)$ for $i > k]$.  This is the same as $ \max [ (1-λ_1 x),  (λ_n x -1)]$ for $ x \in I_k$.  Now you should be able to get a condition for x in terms of  $k^*$ which is the largest $k$ s.t. $λ_k \le \frac{2}{λ_1+λ_n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote $f_j(x)=|1-\lambda_jx|$ and $f(x)=\max_j f_j(x)$.

Each of these functions is made of two affine pieces. Drawing it is highly recommended.

In particular, on $(-\infty,\frac{1}{\lambda_j}]$, it is equal to $1-\lambda_jx$ so its graph is the half-line starting at $(\frac{1}{\lambda_j},0)$ and passing by $(0,1)$. On $[\frac{1}{\lambda_j},+\infty)$, it is worth $\lambda_j x-1$ so its graph is the half-line starting at $(\frac{1}{\lambda_j},0)$ with slope $\lambda_j$.

On $(-\infty,0]$, $f(x)=f_n(x)$ and it is decreasing.

Find the intersection of $f_1$ and $f_n$ on $(0,+\infty)$. You get 
$$
x_0=\frac {2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_n}\qquad f_1(x_0)=f_n(x_0)=\frac{\lambda_n-\lambda_1}{\lambda_n+\lambda_1}.
$$

On $[0,x_0]$, we have $f(x)=f_1(x)$ and it is decreasing.

Finally, on $[x_0,+\infty)$, we find $f(x)=f_n(x)$ and it is increasing.

Therefore the minimum is attained at $x_0$ and we have
$$
\min_\mathbb{R} f=f\left( \frac{2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_n}\right)=\frac{\lambda_n-\lambda_1}{\lambda_n+\lambda_1}.
$$

Note: to prove the claims more carefully, you can do like this.

On $(-\infty,0]$, $0$ is on the left of the zeros of all $f_j$, so
$$
f_j(x)=1-\lambda_jx\leq 1-\lambda_nx=f_n(x)\quad\Rightarrow \quad f(x)=f_n(x)=1-\lambda_nx \quad\forall x\leq 0.
$$

On $[0,x_0]$, $f_n$ is below $f_1$ and we are on the left of the zeros of $f_j$ for $j\leq n-1$, so
$$
f_j(x)=1-\lambda_jx\leq 1-\lambda_1x\quad\Rightarrow\quad f(x)=f_1(x)=1-\lambda_1x \quad \forall x\in [0,x_0].
$$
Finally, on $[x_0,+\infty)$, every $f_j$ is below $f_n$ (I confess I'm waving hands a little here, but this can be made very explicit without difficulty by considering each interval $[1/\lambda_{j+1},1/\lambda_j]$). So
$$
f(x)=f_n(x)=\lambda_nx-1\quad\forall x\geq x_0.
$$
So $f$ is continuous, decreasing on $(-\infty,x_0]$, increasing on $[x_0,+\infty)$. Hence $\min f=f(x_0)$.

Answer (score 0):

this problem from this:we have $||x_{k}-x^{*}||_{A}\le \displaystyle\max_{1\le i\le n}{|1-\alpha\lambda_{i}}|\cdot||x_{k-1}-x^{*}||_{A}
\le\displaystyle\max_{\lambda_{n}\le \lambda\le\lambda_{1}}{|1-\alpha\lambda|}\cdot||x_{k-1}-x^{*}||_{A}$,and $\lambda_{1}>\lambda_{2}>\cdots>\lambda_{n}$

We made the first on the right formula to minimize,we easy

$a=\dfrac{2}{\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{n}}$